# How to view the queries issued by ReactiveMongoRepository?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Repository extending ReactiveMongoRepository with the given method:

```
Mono<MyObject> findByField(String fieldValue);
```

I would like to see the request generated and send to MongoDB in my server console. 
Is that possible ? If so, How ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you try logging the queries ?

Comment: I was looking for a Spring property key bug I will use logging. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may enable `DEBUG` logging for `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate`. 
However, logging in many cases uses blocking operations. Please make sure to check out [reactor-logback](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/tree/master/reactor-logback) for a non blocking alternative.

Comment: Enabling logging displayed the query.Thank you Christoph.